# How to merge same id value into one row but have multiple values in other

Tags: php, mysql, record

I have two tables and I am fetching its data on PHP form but every row show the same value in it for a student now I want to merge 2 or 3 same row first column data into one (dynamically) how can I do that please tell me its same like a student result where student name, father name, roll no. shown in one row either the subjects can be multiple. (I showed the scenario in the image please see)

[image]

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to implement a classic _control break_.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what you asked, the query should be like:

```
create table registration (
id int(9) not null auto_increment,
name varchar(30),
class varchar(30),
email varchar(50),
Primary key id(`id`) );

insert into registration values (1,'A','8','A@gmail.com'), (2,'B','7','B@gmail.com'), (3,'C','9','C@gmail.com'), (4,'D','6','D@gmail.com') ; 

create table subject_detailed (
sid int(9) not null auto_increment,
id int(9) not null ,
subject varchar(30),
marks varchar(30),
Primary key sid(`sid`)  );


insert into subject_detailed values (1,2,'Hindi',50), (2,2,'English',60), (3,1,'GK',70), (4,2,'Maths',30), (5,1,'Hindi',40) ; 


SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',r.name,r.class,r.email) as 'Concate_Column', 
s.subject, s.marks 
from registration r 
inner join subject_detailed s using(id) 
order by Concate_Column ASC ;
```

[image]

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('\n',r.name,r.class,r.email) as 'Concate_Column',  s.subject, s.marks  from registration r  inner join subject_detailed s using(id)  order by Concate_Column ASC;
```

I think the last query is what you are trying to do.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',r.name,r.class,r.email) as 'Concate_Column' , group_concat(s.subject separator ',')  as 'Subject' , group_concat(s.marks  separator ',') as 'Marks'  
from registration r 
inner join subject_detailed s using(id) 
group by Concate_Column
order by Concate_Column ASC ;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Desired Output][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzY7m.png

Please see the output attached image the data you displayed this I understand but here I want to make dynamic row span for column 1
for example Record A having 2 Subject GK and Hindi and record B having 3 Subject Hindi, English, Math's and at the time of fetch records I want to display details of record A only in one row (common for all subject) rather than showing with all subjects separately ,subjects can be many but A,8,A@gmail.com it will be display only 1 time with all the subjects with 2 row span dynamically and if record B having 3 subjects it make row span of 3 rows dynamically for column 1 it can automatically make row span according to the number of subject rows hope you understand me.

Comment: no its not what is need i dont mean to insert records with comma seperator in database i want to fetch records on page where the subjects will be displaying in rows dynamically while the details of student will be common for all the subjects in one column from my query it show name and details with all subject rows which i just want to add up rows according to subject and show one student records please check my last message and output image and compare from first you will understand the change i need to do

Comment: please check this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzY7m.png   I want to display record in this format ,I don't want to concatenate data ,what my problem is when I fetch the records of student it shows name, class, email with each row with subjects I want to display that name only one time with all of its associated subject rows same like as in the mark sheet where the subjects can be displaying in every new row but student information is display only one time common for all rows.